# boost only for front page with cache enabled for other pages?

Tags: 7, performance, caching

I know that [Boost](https://www.drupal.org/project/boost) module works only when drupal cache is disabled.

But is there any way to turn on [Boost](https://www.drupal.org/project/boost) module for front page only, with cache enabled for other pages.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/2078595#comment-7885027 check it

Answer (score 0):

All the node pages either can be added to exception list with Boost or front page.

You can inspect the cache files that boost creates (these are actually plain html files) in the cache apache root folder.